# "Para" and "Paras" vs "Paragraph" and "Paragraphs"

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I find people using "para" for "paragraph" and "paras" for "paragraphs", even in formal English.

See the example sentence:

> In para 2 of the plaint, the plaintiff has stated that he is entitled to "x".

Have "para" and "paras" come of age and gained recognition in formal English. Can I write "para" and "paras" in a formal writing?

Comment: Don't tell the British Parachute Regiment!  Officially and unofficially they are *The Paras*.

Comment: No references here beyond personal interactions, but I see this a lot with (American) lawyers and their contracts. If they need updates, they'll refer to the numbered paragraphs as para/s.

Comment: Depending on the context, sometimes people refer to paragraph elements (xml or html), and sometimes those elements are named "para", not "paragraph". It is also the case that sometimes people abbreviate to "para" in email messages and other informal settings, especially when the term is repeated over and over. I would expect that "para" (as an abbreviation for "paragraph") is used much more in written English than in spoken English.

Comment: It may be valid jargon (legal or otherwise), but it's not "formal" in the formal sense.

Comment: I would advise you to post an example sentence for formal English when you say you find people using them in formal English. Then your question reads better. I am not the downvoter, but I can understand why your question received two downvotes.

Comment: It looks far better. +1)

Comment: I doubt that the above example would be presented in a US court.  Neither *paragraph* nor *complaint* would be abbreviated.  ("Plaint" is a term in British law, but not US law, to my knowledge.)

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, you are correct. "Plaint" is a term in British law. As India was a British colony, several British laws are still in vogue in India. In civil courts in India, the case is still presented by the suer, formally called "plaintiff", by a plaint. In criminal courts, case is, however, presented by a complaint.

Answer (score 1):

In written English, especially formal, I would still use paragraph, although "para" has increased in use. Having a neurology background, where "paraplegia" and "paraparesis" are common terms, I still use "paragraph" exclusively. The language is evolving, and para will become more and more mainstream.